# mixed oscillating circuit resonance frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis

So I have been trying to calculate the oscillating frequency now for a while, but have not been able to. all the textbook examples seem to be either a parallel or series oscillating circuit.
In order to get to the ω i need the complex Resistance of the circuit. This is what I have to far.
The circuits in question are in the other picture.
I am still learning and need an educated help here.
This is kind of a last resort more to ask you guys. I know these kind of questions are not liked, though I am kind of desperate.
Sorry for the german text in them, if people feel required I will redraw the circuits and formula with proper english characterization.
complex resistors for circuit 1/2

[image: Circuilt 1(2) and 2(3)]

Comment: complex resistors I have so far:
http://imgur.com/a/nOrOV
isn't here a way to edit formulas into a post?

Comment: "but have not been able to" - why? The circuit will resonate at f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$. Is it this formula you didn't know?

Comment: No, the f over 2pi*sqrt(LC) isn't the problem. The problem is solving the complex resistance to the ω with the second capacitor and resistor in the circuits above. I have no idea how to solve that equation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "complex" resistor but if you mean any normal resistor then the formula I gave is still the same. However, this seems too simple and, therefore maybe you need to spend some time explaining what it is that you are struggling with.

Comment: OK do you in fact mean a negative resistor i.e. one that causes oscillations?

Comment: He means complex impedance found by applying s or w2pi conversions on the inductors/capacitors.  For example, z_C = 1/(sC) ; z_L = sL.  so basically you do just that.  s = jw.  You just apply the same circuit analysis as you normally would after transforming the elements like this (series/parallel stuff works the same).  then you can find the w (omega) which causes the impedance to be at a min or max, depending on topology, which will be resonance.  this happens when the impedance from the inductors (positive) exactly matches out the impedance (negative) from the capacitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top circuit, CK is in parallel with C1, which makes the circuits identical except for their resonant frequencies.

To prove it, add 4.7nF to C1 in the bottom circuit and solve for its resonance. It should be exactly the same as the resonance of the first circuit.